# Create list of list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose I have three lists

```
[-1,0,1,2]
[0,1]
[a,b,c]
```

I would like to obtain a list as

```
[-1,0,a]
[-1,0,b]
[-1,0,c]

[-1,1,a]
[-1,1,b]
[-1,1,c]

[0,0,a]
[0,0,b]
[0,0,c]
...
```

How to write a python function to achieve this goal?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show a [mcve] of your latest attempt please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
from pprint import pprint

l = [[-1, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
result = list(product(*l))
pprint(result)
```

Result:

```
[(-1, 0, 'a'),
 (-1, 0, 'b'),
 (-1, 0, 'c'),
 (-1, 1, 'a'),
 (-1, 1, 'b'),
 (-1, 1, 'c'),
 (0, 0, 'a'),
 (0, 0, 'b'),
 (0, 0, 'c'),
 (0, 1, 'a'),
 (0, 1, 'b'),
 (0, 1, 'c'),
 (1, 0, 'a'),
 (1, 0, 'b'),
 (1, 0, 'c'),
 (1, 1, 'a'),
 (1, 1, 'b'),
 (1, 1, 'c'),
 (2, 0, 'a'),
 (2, 0, 'b'),
 (2, 0, 'c'),
 (2, 1, 'a'),
 (2, 1, 'b'),
 (2, 1, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use list comprehension

```
l1 = [-1,0,1,2]
l2 = [0,1]
l3 = ['a','b','c']
[[i,j,k] for i in l1 for j in l2 for k in l3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your example! However, I may encounter case which starts from four lists. Anyway Robᵩ's answer seems to be powerful !